# Adobe Air iOS capture first-time app use

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I would like to create a quick tutorial for the app when it first time been opened.

Is there a way you can actually do this? Would you create a text file under the appIDfolder and update the value when first time it been open. so it will differentiated if it was first time used? or any better ideas or suggestion.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I did - `File.applicationStorageDirectory` is your friend.  Just write a small file there.  You could store the version number, last access, etc. there so you'd have some options ("Welcome back, it's been a long time", "Here are the features in the new version", etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It can as I do

- 1.) Create 2 Files 1 with a really short tut. and another with more stuff.
- 2.) Test if file exists tutorialShort.txt.
- 3.) Show this file as a quick tut.
- 4.) After viewing. ask Users, next time the App starts => they want to see this tutorial again.
- 5.) Answ:No => only delete or rename tutorialShort.txt